# How to remove brackets and quotations when exporting a list of tuples to TSV

Tags: python, csv

I have a list which, when printed, looks like:

```
[(('1321', '01'), ('MessageXZY', '02'), ('DescriptionSKS', '03'), ('S7_6', '04'), ('S7_3', '05')), (('0A3B', '06'), ('MessageZYA', '07'), ('DescriptionKAM', '08')), (('9K44', '09'), ('MessageYAL', '10'), ('DescriptionAUS', '11'), ('S7_2', '12'))]
```

When I export using the following code:

```
with open('HTML to TSV.tsv','w',encoding='ISO-8859-1') as out:
    tsv_out = csv.writer(out, delimiter="\t")
    for row in grouped_tuples:
        tsv_out.writerow(row)
```

I get the following in the text/TSV file:

```
('1321', '01')  ('MessageXZY', '02')    ('DescriptionSKS', '03')    ('S7_6', '04')  ('S7_3', '05')
('0A3B', '06')  ('MessageZYA', '07')    ('DescriptionKAM', '08')
('9K44', '09')  ('MessageYAL', '10')    ('DescriptionAUS', '11')    ('S7_2', '12')
```

Desired output:

```
1321, 01     MessageXZY, 02     DescriptionSKS, 03     S7_6, 04     S7_3, 05
0A3B, 06     MessageZYA, 07     DescriptionKAM, 08
9K44, 09     MessageYAL, 10     DescriptionAUS, 11     S7_2, 12
```

I would rather not search for and remove **')** from the entries as my actual strings my legitimately contain that combination. What can I do do so that the **csv.writer()** doesn't write these characters?

Comment: Explain what you want the output to be.

Comment: you can make the output nicer but accessing the tuple values like this: https://image.prntscr.com/image/bToOjco2TTSpNbuamlZ7yQ.png

Comment: post you actual input list, you current list is invalid and throws an error

Comment: I have edited in the actual list. It should work now

Answer (score 1):

You could group the pairs together before writing them:

```
import csv

grouped_tuples = [(('1321', '01'), ('MessageXZY', '02'), ('DescriptionSKS', '03'), ('S7_6', '04'), ('S7_3', '05')), (('0A3B', '06'), ('MessageZYA', '07'), ('DescriptionKAM', '08')), (('9K44', '09'), ('MessageYAL', '10'), ('DescriptionAUS', '11'), ('S7_2', '12'))]

with open('HTML to TSV.tsv','w', encoding='ISO-8859-1', newline='') as out:
    tsv_out = csv.writer(out, delimiter="\t")

    for row in grouped_tuples:
        tsv_out.writerow(', '.join(pair) for pair in row)
```

Giving you:

```
1321, 01    MessageXZY, 02  DescriptionSKS, 03  S7_6, 04    S7_3, 05
0A3B, 06    MessageZYA, 07  DescriptionKAM, 08
9K44, 09    MessageYAL, 10  DescriptionAUS, 11  S7_2, 12
```

Answer (score 0):

in place of

```
    tsv_out.writerow(row)
```

give

```
    tsv_out.writerow((row[0],row[1]))
```

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited, immediate help.  A proper explanation [would greatly improve](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) its long-term value by showing *why* this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions.  Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you've made.